# Parsing a very large JSON file with backslashes (JSON encoded)

Tags: python, json, screen-scraping

I'm looking to grab some data from a very large JSON file in Python. The issue is this file has over 15,000,000 columns (single lined), and I'm unaware of how to get past the formatting as this JSON file has a lot of backslashes and starts/ends with a quotation mark.

Here's my Python code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for i in range(0, 2):
    pprint("Data output: " + data['ObjectData'][i]['column1'])
```

This works excellently when I take an manually copy an object from that JSON file and format it properly like so:

```
{
    "Result": "Result String",
    "ObjectData": [
        {
            "Column 1": "Data",
            "Column 2": "Data",
            "Column 3": "Data",
            "Column 4": "Data",
            "Column 5": "Data",
        },
        {
            "Column 1": "Data 2",
            "Column 2": "Data 2",
            "Column 3": "Data 2",
            "Column 4": "Data 2",
            "Column 5": "Data 2",
        }
    ]
}
```

My output is like so, which is exactly what I want.

```
Data output: Data
Data output: Data 2
```

But this is the actual format of the file, wrapped in a double quote and all (I did format this for readability here, but an example of single lined is pasted below):

```
"{
\"Result\":\"Result String\",
\"ObjectData\":[
{
\"Column 1\":\"Data\",
\"Column 2\":\"Data\",
\"Column 3\":\"Data\",
\"Column 4\":\"Data\",
\"Column 5\":\"Data\"
},
{
\"Column 1\":\"Data 2\",
\"Column 2\":\"Data 2\",
\"Column 3\":\"Data 2\",
\"Column 4\":\"Data 2\",
\"Column 5\":\"Data 2\"
}]}"
```

Here is how it actually looks in the file:

```
"{\"Result\":\"Result String\",\"ObjectData\":[{\"Column 1\":\"Data\",\"Column 2\":\"Data\",\"Column 3\":\"Data\",\"Column 4\":\"Data\",\"Column 5\":\"Data\"},{\"Column 1\":\"Data 2\",\"Column 2\":\"Data 2\",\"Column 3\":\"Data 2\",\"Column 4\":\"Data 2\",\"Column 5\":\"Data 2\"}]}"
```

My first thought was to try and beautify the code into the format I want. However, it's a very large JSON file with 15 million columns as I mentioned so it wouldn't ever run without crashing.

Is there an easier way to handle this? I've been trying to find if I'm missing a basic principle here, but I've never seen a JSON formatted this way.

Any guidance is appreciated, thanks so much.

Comment: When you save the JSON object to file, you have to save it as a string. You cannot save the JSON object as object as you wont be able to read it. When you saive it as string, the double quotes are escaped. Double quotes are required for json keys and values.

Comment: You appear to have data encoded to JSON **twice**.

Comment: Perhaps you should load the json into pandas dataframe and work from there..

Comment: @RoyGranit: not everything is a datascience nail, please put down that hammer. *Not everything needs Pandas*, not everyone knows how to use it and not everything is magically better with a dataframe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters your duplicate doesn't exactly tell how to load that though. Perhaps it was someone else who produced the file, as OP is baffled with it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala This is correct, the file was loaded from a web-source that used it to display data on the page for their infinite scroll site. Thankfully I was able to decode it, not realizing that was the issue in the first place.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: yeah, it's not a good duplicate, I was to hasty there. Surprisingly, I can't find a better one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as if the JSON file has been double-encoded. Perhaps you could do

```
with open('file.json') as f:
    decoded_once = json.load(f)
    data = json.loads(decoded_once)
```

It is hard to tell from that excerpt alone what has happened.

If that one fails, perhaps because the outer string comes from *Python instead*, the fix would be to use `ast.literal_eval` for the first step:

```
import ast
with open('file.json') as f:
    decoded_once = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
    data = json.loads(decoded_once)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Decoding the file worked as intended.